# Add items from NSSet to UITableView (convert NSSet to multiple arrays?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsset

I have a UITableView that adds information from a Core Data the following way:

1. The "Category" for various names is added at the header
2. The names that correspond to the Category should be loaded in cells beneath the Category

Right now I have the header loading the right name and the right number of sections and rows being added. However - the results from Core Data are being returned as an NSSet, so I can't add each name to the cells based on the indexPath.row.

Any suggestions? For reference:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[dataToUse objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]valueForKey:@"heldBy"]valueForKey:@"name"]];
```

Returns the appropriate set of names to each cell of the appropriate section, but it returns the ENTIRE set to each cell. I just want each name to be added based on which row it's a part of. I can solve this by converting the NSSet to an Array, but since there are multiple sets being created (because there are multiple categories) I don't see how I can do this.

EDIT: I fixed my problem by doing the following, but I'm still interested to know what the best thing to do would have been.

```
NSSet *daset = [[dataToUse objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]valueForKey:@"heldBy"];
NSMutableArray *addToLabel = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
int i = 0;
for(NSSet *contact in daset) {
    [addToLabel insertObject:[contact valueForKey:@"name"] atIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"%@",addToLabel);
    i++;
}
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[addToLabel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: `NSFetchedResultsController` does exactly what you need (presents your rows organized into sections based on your CoreData model graph). [Take a look at the docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: My fellow developer told me this is the case. I'm going to stick with my solution just so I can move on, but it's top of my list for things to go back to ASAP. Thanks man! If you post that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: You're welcome. I've added the answer and I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `NSFetchedResultsController`

It's designed to do exactly what you're looking for. For straight forward cases like yours, where you just need your data organized into sections based on your model relationships it will offload a lot of weight off your shoulders by automatically managing the fetching, editing, caching etc. You can find [**a nice tutorial here**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller) and of course the [**official documentation here**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

To convert from NSSet->NSArray you need to sort the set with a NSSortDescriptior. Something like:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"nm" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

  NSArray *arr = [[myset allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```

Comment: Yes, the result of the fetch is an array (because I did that) but it's an array of NSSets. Does that make sense? So I can get, for example, the name of the first NSSet, but I need the name of each indexPath.row for a relationship (that I call @"heldBy") which ITSELF is also a Set because that's how it's returned.

Answer (score 0):

NSSortDescriptor *sort=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSArray *arr = [[myset allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

"nsset object" *nssetObject =[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",nssetObject.name];